# htaccess redirect root to subdomain, but leave subfolders intact

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been searching all over and have found problems similar to this but not the same.
I want domain.com to redirect to news.domain.com, however, I want domain.com/page to stay at domain.com/page.

Currently I'm using:

```
RedirectMatch 301 http://domain.com[/] http://news.domain.com
```

But it moves domain.com/page to news.domain.compage (which obviously isn't even a valid address).

Answer (score 0):

If you just redirect the domain name alone, you can do that in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://news.domain.com [R=302,L]
```

Change to [R=301,L] when that work well.